# How do I make a WinDivert program with the precompiled driver modules?

Tags: c, windows, networking, compilation, wfp

I need to use [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) to make a program. I'm confused how to make and compile a C program that uses the precompiled WinDivert.dll, WinDivert.sys, WinDivert.inf, and WdfCoInstaller*.dll files.

For example, if I wanted to compile the [passthru](http://reqrypt.org/samples/passthru.html) example with some modifications, how do I do it?

The precompiled driver modules seem to work fine, as do the precompiled samples, but I need to make a program of my own.

Notes: I'm using windows 8.1. I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and WDK 8.1 installed. I don't think it works with Visual Studio, or if it does, I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using LoadLibrary()/GetProcAddress() to dynamically load WinDivert.dll.  This is a reasonably foolproof method that should work for any compiler/library combination.

Comment: My program works perfectly on desktop, but on my laptop and my friend's laptop I get `error: failed to open the WinDivert device (1275)`. I've tried disabling antivirus and the firewall, but neither has worked. My laptop and desktop are both 64 bit windows 8.1. Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: More details on this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117687/what-is-blocking-driver-installation-in-windows).

Comment: Apart from what is already documented in the [WinDivert FAQ](http://reqrypt.org/windivert-faq.html‎), I do not know what else can cause this error.