# What is blocking driver installation in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, installation, driver, wfp

I've written a C program in Windows that uses some precompiled files from [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html). My program uses a .dll from WinDivert and some of the functions in the .dll install the WinDivert.sys driver. There are also a few more files from WinDivert that are a part of this (a .lib, a .inf, and another .dll).

The problem is that on one of my computers (Windows 8.1 64 bit), everything works perfectly. But, when I try to use the program on my laptop (Windows 8.1 64), my friend's laptop (Windows 7 64), or another Windows 7 64 desktop, something blocks the installation of the driver. I'm unsure what is blocking it or how to stop it from being blocked because on all computers:

+I'm running on an admin profile

+Running the program in admin command prompt

+Tried disabling firewall, anti virus, etc (although it runs fine with these on for the computer that works)

+As far as I can tell, all my security settings are the same

+Note: the driver does have a valid signature.

Why does the driver install perfectly on one computer, but not on the other three? What could be issue?

Comment: Have you tried going into _Control Panel_ -> _Administrative Tools_ -> _Event Viewer_ and then looking into _Windows Logs_, best soon after the installation fails. Sadly I don't remember into which one of the logs (_Application_ / _Security_ / _Setup_ / _System_) this would go into but maybe you can find an event there that would give you some kind of clue.

Comment: @user2802841 In the Event Viewer (under system) there are 2 Information and 2 Error entries when I run the program (on a computer which the driver is blocked).

Info: A service was installed in the system. Service name: WinDivert1.1 File: C:/etc/etc/WinDivert.sys

Info: "The description for Event ID 26 from source Application Popup cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event " continued in next comment...

Comment: "If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

\??\C:\Users\\etc\etc\WinDivert.sys failed to load

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table"

Error: "The description for Event ID 1060 from source Application Popup cannot be found. (the rest of the description is the same as the previous)"

Error: "The WinDivert1.1 service failed to start due to the following error: 
This driver has been blocked from loading"

Comment: I've done some googling and I have no idea what any of this means. I've tried downloading new files from WinDivert in case something was corrupted, but that hasn't worked. Neither has recompiling my code on my laptop.

Comment: Are you read carefully WinDivert documentation? VS redist must be installed.

Comment: I installed a few versions of MS C++ redistributables and it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

The main causes for 1275 errors are documented on the [WinDivert FAQ](http://reqrypt.org/windivert-faq.html).  However, there may be other causes that I'm unaware of (perhaps some experts out there can help?)

Another thing to try is the following commands:

```
sc stop WinDivert1.1
sc delete WinDivert1.1
```

Comment: When I run those commands, I get OpenService FAILED 1060: the specified service does not exist as an installed service.

I was hoping someone with Windows expertise could see this; I don't think anything is wrong with the WinDivert files.